# Retrieve Field from Symfony2 Repository object

Tags: php, symfony, repository

When I am working Symfony Repository. When I retrieve date it displaying an object, I want to get a specific field from that object.

The date which is already stored in DB. I want to retrieve that using repository method.

Code :

```
echo "<pre>";
        $cd = $contract->getContractDate();
        print_r($cd);
       print_r($cd->date); // date field is not coming
        exit;
```

Output :

```
  DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2012-03-24 00:00:00.000000
                [timezone_type] => 3
                [timezone] => America/New_York
            )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer depends on what field do you want to extract.

`\DateTime` is internal PHP Class and has different methods to work with.
Examples:

```
echo (new \DateTime())->format('Y-m-d'); // 2017-01-12
echo (new \DateTime('2017-01-07'))->format('Y-m-d'); // 2017-01-07
echo (new \DateTime())->getTimezone()->getName(); // Europe/Moscow
```

In your case you don't need to extract it, as you have all necessary methods to work with. E.g.

```
$cd->format('Y-m-d');
```

More about it: http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: i want to get the `date` from the Object. conversation is next step.

Comment: there is no need to get `date` (as string) as you have all necessary methods in `\DateTime`. It's OOP style.

Comment: You misunderstood my question, its not for the current date, the date which is already stored in DB. i want to retrieve that using repository method.

Comment: Added example from your question